# how to filter my check box when I write in input in jquery in below code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to filter my check box in below code.when I am writing in the input with class "js-filter-input" , I want to show only the check box with value of "js-filter-input" input .for example I write uni 1 in input and I want to show only checkbox with the value of unni 1 and the other ckeckbox are become hide.but my code don't  work correctly.

```js
$( document ).on( 'keyup', '.js-filter-input', function () { 
    var val;
    var $content =$( this ).parent().next().find( ".search-filter-con" ).find( '.label-name' ).text() + " ";
    if ( val = $( this ).val() ) {
        
        $( '.group-checkbox .label-name', $content ).each( function () {
            var patt = new RegExp( val, 'i' );
            if ( patt.test( $( this ).data( 'en' ) ) || patt.test( $( this ).data( 'fa' ) ) || patt.test( $( this ).data( 'search' ) ) ) {
                $( this ).parent().show();
            } else {
                $( this ).parent().hide();
            }
        } );
    } else {
        $( '.group-checkbox', $content ).show();
    }
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-container2">
  <input class="search_box js-filter-input" placeholder="" name="" type="text">
  <button value="" class="search_submit" name="search_submit" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</div>
<div class="searchList">
  <div class="sampleContainer mCustomScrollbar _mCS_3 mCS-dir-rtl mCS_no_scrollbar">
    <div class="mCustomScrollBox mCS-light-thin mCSB_vertical mCSB_inside">
      <div class="mCSB_container mCS_y_hidden mCS_no_scrollbar_y" dir="rtl">
        <div class="search-filter-con">
          <div class="group-checkbox">
            <div class="squaredFour">
              <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="uni1" name="check" />
              <label for="uni1"></label>
            </div>
            <label class="label-name" for="uni1" data-fa="uni1" data-en="uni1" data-search="uni1>uni1</label>
          </div>
          <div class="group-checkbox">
            <div class="squaredFour">
              <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="uni2" name="check" />
              <label for="uni2"></label>
            </div>
            <label class="label-name" for="uni2" data-fa="uni2" data-en="uni2" data-search="uni2">uni2</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you expect from alert to return??

Comment: the value of  <label class="label-name" for="uni1">uni 1</label> for example uni 1

Comment: In your example .. `.search-filter-con` element has two `label-name` not just one .. so the code will return both of them .. `$(this).parent().next().find(".search-filter-con").find('.label-name').text()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In your example .. .search-filter-con element has two label-name not
>   just one .. so the code will return both of them ..
>   `$(this).parent().next().find(".search-filter-con").find('.label-name').text()`

To get a separated text you need to use `.each()` to loop through the labels

```
$(this).parent().next().find(".search-filter-con").find('.label-name').each(function(){
   console.log($(this).text() + ',');
});
```

<sup>I don't know what is the purpose of using `$(this).parent().next()` Unless you've multiple inputs and divs with the same classes and you want to refer to each one of them</sup>

To use `input` to filter you can use `.filter()` with `indexOf()`

```js
$(document).on('input', '.js-filter-input', function() {
  var val = $(this).val().trim();
  if (val !== '') {
    $(this).parent().next().find(".group-checkbox").hide().find('.label-name').filter(function(){
      var FaData = $(this).data('fa');
      var EnData = $(this).data('en');
      return FaData.indexOf(val) > -1 || EnData.indexOf(val) > -1; 
    }).closest('.group-checkbox').show();
  }else{
    $('.group-checkbox').show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-container2">
  <input class="search_box js-filter-input" placeholder="" name="" type="text">
  <button value="" class="search_submit" name="search_submit" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</div>
<div class="searchList">
  <div class="sampleContainer mCustomScrollbar _mCS_3 mCS-dir-rtl mCS_no_scrollbar">
    <div class="mCustomScrollBox mCS-light-thin mCSB_vertical mCSB_inside">
      <div class="mCSB_container mCS_y_hidden mCS_no_scrollbar_y" dir="rtl">
        <div class="search-filter-con">
          <div class="group-checkbox">
            <div class="squaredFour">
              <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="uni1" name="check" />
              <label for="uni1"></label>
            </div>
            <label class="label-name" for="uni1" data-fa="امير كبير" data-en="امير كبير" data-search="uni1">امير كبير</label>
          </div>
          <div class="group-checkbox">
            <div class="squaredFour">
              <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="uni2" name="check" />
              <label for="uni2"></label>
            </div>
            <label class="label-name" for="uni2" data-fa="تهران" data-en="تهران" data-search="uni2">تهران</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tnx for your help . I I have some check box and I want to filter my check box when I am writing in input with class "js-input-filter"

Comment: @elhamb .. Do you find a solution??

Comment: your code answer to my question but I dont solve my main problem . that is  I want to filter my check box when I am writing in input with class "js-input-filter" .for example when I type uni 1 in input only show  to me the check box with uni 1 and the other check box become hide

Comment: I Edit my question again

Comment: Me too @elhamb .. I Edit the snippet in the answer .. Please take a look

Comment: Tnx alot for your help.its work well for English words.but I dont Know why it doesnt work for persian words... .for example I wtire دانشگاه تهران instead of uni 1 anf I write دانشگاه امیر کبیر instead of uni 2 .but when I write in input.don ' t find them and all of checkbox are become hide ...

Comment: I found the problem .in my project . I have this error. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined . and I use the jquery 3.1.1

Comment: @elhamb I edit the snippet again .. and it works for Arabic words

Comment: yes it works well . but in my project I dont konw why it dont know property 'indexOf' .

Comment: @elhamb Copy/paste my code instead of your code and try again and check every `.label-name` has a defined `data` attribute ..

Comment: Mohamed-Yousef : I have a same question like this.can u help me?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56721167/how-to-filter-my-list-when-i-write-in-input-in-jquery-in-below-code