# how to filter my list when I write in input in jquery in below code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of jobs and I want to filter it so when I am writing in the input with class `js-filter-input` it only shows `li` matching the value of `js-filter-input`. For example, I want to find a painter. But my code doesn't work correctly. Most of my code works, but this part `.closest( '.result .tests ul .li' ).show();` that tries to find `li` doesn't work correctly. How would I fix it?

```
<input class="search_box js-filter-input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="search ..." name="search_key" type="text">
<button value="" class="search_submit" name="search_submit" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
   <div class="result">
    <div class="tests">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-fa="writer" title="">writer</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#" data-fa="painter" title="">painter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-fa="programmer" title="">programmer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-fa="web designer" title="">web designer</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

java script:

```
$(document).on('input', '.js-filter-input', function() {
  var val = $(this).val().trim();

  if (val !== '') {
    $(".mid-row .search-container .result,.search-container2 .result").fadeIn(200);

    $(this).parent().find('.result .tests ul li a').filter(function() {
      var FaData = $(this).data('fa');
      return FaData.indexOf(val) > -1;
    }).closest('.result .tests ul .li').show();
  } else {
    $(".result .tests ul .li").show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Time to review: https://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Change `.closest('.result .tests ul .li').show();` to `.closest('li').show();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this by using the jQuery filter function.

```js
$(document).on('input', '.js-filter-input', function() {
    var inpVal = this.value; 
    var reg = new RegExp(inpVal, "i");
    var selector = $('.tests ul li');
    if(inpVal){
      selector.hide().filter(function(){
        return $(this).find('a').data('fa').match(reg);
      }).show();
    } else {
       selector.show();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="search_box js-filter-input" autocomplete="off" placeholder="search ..." name="search_key" type="text">
<button value="" class="search_submit" name="search_submit" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
   <div class="result">
    <div class="tests">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" data-fa="writer" title="">writer</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#" data-fa="painter" title="">painter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-fa="programmer" title="">programmer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-fa="web designer" title="">web designer</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('input[name="key"]').on('input', function (e) {

  !this.value
    ? $('.job').show()
    : $('.job').hide().filter('[data-fa*="' + this.value.toLowerCase() + '"]').show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <input type="text" name="key" />
</form>

<output>
  <ul>
    <li class="job" data-fa="writer">Writer</li>
    <li class="job" data-fa="painter">Painter</li>
    <li class="job" data-fa="programmer">Programmer</li>
  </ul>
</output>
```

Comment: Change your selector to `*=` instead of `^=` and I think you have a winner

Comment: @msg Ah, a good idea! I I've gone ahead updated the code snippet.